# setting covariance and params for robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone ,

This  link [odom and imu covariances,](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dz4664k0iy5cwfb/covariances.jpg?dl=0) is my odom0 and imu0 config,odom_pose_covariace, odom_twist_covariance, imu_orientation_covariace, imu_angular_velocity_covariance and imu_linear_acceleration_covariace  picture(sorry ,i can't upload this picture).The left-up of the picture  is  odom0_config and Imu0_config,according to [robot_localization_Fusing Unmeasured Variables](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/configuring_robot_localization.html#fusing-unmeasured-variables),I use odom: `X˙,Y˙and yaw˙`and imu: `yaw,yaw˙and X¨`to fuse . The left-down of the picture is  imu `orientation_covariance`,`angular_velocity_covariace`and`linear_acceleration_covariance`.The right of the picture is `odom_pose_covariance`and `odom_twist_covariance`. Althrough i see some similar questions like [these](http://answers.ros.org/question/220769/setting-covariances-for-robot_localization/),i still have some confusions :

- `Q1`  As we all know ,to 2d differential robot, odom  output data:  `Z, vy(linear_y),vz(linear_z),wx(angular_x) and wy(angular_y)`are all  zero ,so when we setting  the  covariance for `Z,roll,pitch,vy(linear_y),vz(linear_z),wx(angular_x) and wy(angular_y)`,should we set them  a very very small value like 1e-6 ,or should we set them  zero?
- `Q2` In the odom covariance for `x`,`y`and `yaw`,i set them  are 0.01,0.01 and 0.1(actually,i have no experiance about how to set them).And then ,i think odom twist is more accurate than pose ,so i set odom_twist_covariance  for `X˙`and `yaw˙`is smaller than `x`and `yaw`. Covariance for `X˙`is 0.001,and for `yaw˙`is 0.01.This practice is reasonable ？？

---

In addition to the above questions，i have some questions about `robot_localization`params setting .

- I see  the [~[sensor]_differential](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#sensor-differential) , [~[sensor]_relative](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#sensor-relative) ：
- -**The first kind of understaning**： i think if one source is enabled differential ,`r_l` will differentiate the variables which be  used to fuse.For example,If we set odom0_config is `X˙,Y˙and yaw˙`and set `odom0_differential:true`,does it mean that :`r_l`will convert `X˙,Y˙and yaw˙`  to `X¨,Y¨,yaw''`to following calculation.
- **The second kind of understaning:** if one source is enabled differential ,`r_l` will differentiate the only pose  variables `X,Y,Z,roll,pitch,yaw`.But  if  when  we set  odom0_config is `X˙,Y˙and yaw˙`and set `odom0_differential:true`,there is none of  pose variables such as `X,Y,Z,roll,pitch,yaw`.
- `Q3`So i'm confused about this param meaning.
- `Q4`when i see  [The differential and relative Parameters](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/configuring_robot_localization.html#the-differential-and-relative-parameters),i have one odom and one imu .So which sensor i should `enable differential`,imu or odom ?
- `Q5`Suppose we set `odom_differential:true` ,and `imu_differential:false`,does it mean  that we must also set `odom_relative:false` and `imu_relative:true`? For  the same sensor,we cannot set its differential and relative the  same ,such as : false-false or true-true,because the differential and relative param  are opposite meaning? Am i right?
- `Q6` AS @Tom Moore saied in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/220769/setting-covariances-for-robot_localization/), if you are measuring a variable, make the diagonal value in `initial_estimate_covariance` **larger** than that measurement's covariance.In my case (one odom and one imu),the diagonal value in `initial_estimate_covariance` should be **larger** than odom or imu ,or both of them ? In other words，odom  belong to measurement or  not ?  In our case , `odom :X˙,Y˙,yaw˙` are in question( because odom0_config  above ) and `imu:yaw,yaw˙,X¨`(because imu0_config above ) are in question .when we set `initial_estimate_covariance` for `yaw˙`, we should **larger** than whose covariance for `yaw˙`,odom ? or imu?

---

Any advice will be appreciated much ,if i describe my question not clearly,please let me know .

JXL   China

---

EDIT1:

- As Tom saied,when we have greater than or equal to two  pose inputs that measure the same variable, but they diverge from each other, we  can use the _differential parameter to force one (or all) of them to be treated as a velocity.So in my configure:  odom(X',Y',Yaw') and imu(Yaw,Yaw',X'')configs,  i should set imu0_differential is false.And because _differential setting only applies to pose variables,it is meaningless for twist data and accle data，So i should set my odom0_differential is false.
- Q7:when i have one odom and one imu, in `r_l EKF update cycle`, does it mean there will be one predict step(Kinematic model) and two correct steps,one for odom ,and the other for imu?   But when i see the [predict step](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/indigo-devel/src/filter_base.cpp#L224),for one measurement , there will be  one predict step and one [correct step](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/indigo-devel/src/filter_base.cpp#L230) ,as long as `(delta = measurement.time_ - lastMeasurementTime_,delta>0)`.  Am i wrong ?
- Q8: Why `initial_estimate_covariance` in ekf_template.yaml is so  small(`1e-9`)? To make filter quickly converge,  should we set it a little bigger (1e-3,1e-2 or something)?
- Q9: you say i should have some principled means of determining the covariance data for my sensors.Did you know whether exist some knowledge or guidance on how to set odom and imu covariance in somewhere?How you did your odom and imu coverance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250980/setting-covariance-and-params-for-robot_localization/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-12-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would probably be easier to just post your configuration files from r_l, but I think I have the gist of what you're saying. Also, as some of these questions are unrelated, it might be better in the future to ask multiple questions. Regardless, here goes:

**Answer to Q1**

If your sensor configuration is set to only fuse X velocity, Y velocity, yaw, yaw velocity, and X acceleration, then the covariance matrix values for the other values don't matter (i.e., you can set them to anything). The filter will only use the state and covariance data from the variables you decide to fuse.

**Answer to Q2**

You are not fusing X, Y, and yaw from the wheel encoders, so their covariance values don't matter. In general, though, you would usually see static covariances for the velocity data that accumulates in the pose data.

**Answer to Q3**

The `_differential` setting *only* applies to pose variables. It will differentiate pose measurements and generate velocities from them, then fuse those values. You need to set the pose variables to *true* in the sensor configuration in that case. The `_differential` parameter is meaningless for twist data.

**Answer to Q4**

The use case for the `_differential` parameter is pretty small: if you have two pose inputs that measure the same variable, but they diverge from each other, you can use the `_differential` parameter to force one (or both) of them to be treated as a velocity, which will keep the filter's pose output from oscillating. In your configuration above, you are fusing only one pose variable (yaw), with the rest being velocities and accelerations, so you're all set.

**Answer to Q5**

Again, this won't apply to you, but in general, the `_relative` and `_differential` parameters are mutually exclusive. In fact, if you set both to true, [the relative parameter gets ignored](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ros_filter.cpp#L876).

**Answer to Q6**

It's up to you, really. Ideally, you would have some principled means of determining the covariance data for your sensors, and then just set the `initial_estimate_covariance` to be larger than at least one of them. This is just to aid in accepting the initial measurements from your sensors: if the EKF's initial yaw velocity variance is 0.00001, and the first IMU measurement has a yaw velocity variance of 0.01, the filter isn't going to trust the measurement very much, and so it will be slow to converge. If both of your sensors have relatively high frequencies, it won't really matter whether the initial variance is higher than only one of them, since you're bound to get a measurement very quickly.

**Answer to Q7**

The number of measurements in the update cycle is irrelevant. The filter will look at the delta between the last measurement time stamp and the current one, do a predict across that time step, then correct for the new measurement, and update the last measurement time stamp. If there is another measurement in the queue, it will do the same thing, and so on, until the queue is empty.

**Answer to Q8**

I'd prefer not to make assumptions about what data you plan to fuse. I expect users are going to have to tweak parameters to get things working optimally. I also address this very issue in the [wiki](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#initial-estimate-covariance).

**Answer to Q9**

Many IMUs will report their error rates in their documentation. For odometry, I've previously used a source of ground truth, e.g., motion capture systems, to determine error rates. You could do less high-tech versions and try things as simple as driving your robot in a long, straight line, and seeing how the measured distance traveled compares to your odometry.

If you have further questions, I would recommend posting them as new questions, rather than adding any more to this one.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-01-04**:
@Tom,thanks very very much!!!  To Q4, do you mean for odom(X',Y',Yaw') and imu(Yaw,Yaw',X'')configs,i should set both them `_differential`are false,because as you say,i have only one input(imu) for pose(yaw) and `_differential` is meaningless for twist data?

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-01-04**:
To Q6, you say i should have some principled means of determining the covariance data for my sensors.Did you know whether exist some knowledge or guidance on how to set odom and imu covariance in somewhere?How you did  your odom and imu?

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-01-04**:
BTW,when i have one odom and one imu, in EKF update cycle, does it means there will be one predict step(Kinematic model) and two correct steps,one for odom ,and the other for imu?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-01-13**:
Can you please update your question with these? Thanks!

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-01-17**:
Apologise for delay reply,thanks tom!!!

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-01-18**:
Thanks very very much !!! I learned a lot of things~~~

**Comment by [HIT_LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/80867/hit_lr/) on 2022-01-13**:
兄弟你好，我也是深圳的，最近也是在使用r_l碰到了小问题,能否请教一下呢。